# What is the word for someone who doesn't care about the consequences but is fully aware of them?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for the word for a person that is fully aware of the consequences of his actions or inactions but just doesn't care about them. Neither about the good consequences for himself/others nor about the bad consequences for himself/others.
Is there a specific word for that? Or does imprudent fit it?

Example: Tom is such a not-about-future-consequences-carer! He knows this will cause him trouble in the future, it has caused him trouble in the past, but he just does it anyway.

Comment: Collins Dictionary: [*not care **for** sb/sth*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/not-care-for-sb-sth) - *to **not like** something or someone*.

Comment: [insouciant,](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/insouciant) nonchalant, untroubled, unworried, unruffled, unconcerned, lacking concern, indifferent, blasé, heedless, relaxed, calm, equable, equanimous, serene, composed, casual, easy, easy-going, airy, breezy, carefree, free and easy, free from care, free from worry, happy-go-lucky, light-hearted, frivolous, unserious,...

Comment: Thank you @FumbleFingers :) I sometimes loose track of my verbs, wouldn't have caught that one without you.

Comment: Note that there likely is a psychological term, in the vicinity of "psychopathic".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Tom is so **incautious**! He knows this will cause him trouble in the future, it has caused him trouble in the past, but he just does it anyway.*

**incautious**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/incautious)

> adj. Not cautious; rash.

Answer (score 2):

Per the OED:
Reckless *adj*

> Heedless of or indifferent to the consequences of one's actions; lacking in prudence or caution; willing or liable to take risks; rash, foolhardy; irresponsible.

For your example, you would need to change it slightly as this isn't a noun:

> Tom is so reckless! He knows this will cause him trouble in the future, it has caused him trouble in the past, but he just does it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think this person can be called

***daredevil***

"a person who seeks out very dangerous or foolhardy adventures with no apparent fear"

([Merriam-Webster's Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/daredevil) )